# How to create RDD partitions across columns in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a csv file that looks like this :

Time(in secs) Measure1 Measure2 Measure3..... Measuren

0

0.25

0.50

0.75

1

...

3600

I wish to create custom partitions across this file such that the partitions look like this :

Partition1

time(in secs) measure1

---

Partition2

time(in secs) measure2

---

...

Partitionn

time(in secs) measuren

---

I want to do this as I want to calculate the aggregates such as mean,median etc for each measurement.

And the idea being if I use mapPartitions to do an operation for e.g mean on one partition it will happen in parellel across all partitions.

I wish to avoid using groupBy columnn value as it will cause shuffling operations

Is there a way I can achieve this ?

Thank you.

Regards,

Vinay Joglekar

Answer (score 0):

Well I would do it this way:

1. a function that takes the file as input then reads 4 lines and merges those in some collection type of your choice and yields it. This will go one until there is nothing to read from file.

   2. map on the output of that function, and turn the (for example List is the collection of your choice) yielded Lists into a DataFrame.
   3. Then do whatever using describe() or any other aggregate function.